# Xamarin: Redirect for login and return to same page

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In my app for both iOS and Android to perform certain features in a list view, i want the user to go back to login page if they are not logged in. Once they are logged in, i want them to come back to the same item in the list view they were before.

Can i get some piece of code for that?

UPDATE:

I am using MVVMCross & want to let the user post comments to the items displayed in list view only if he is logged in.

My code:

```
private async void PostIfLoggedIn(bool AddCmnt)
{
 //..
await GotoLogin();
//..        
}

Task<bool> GotoLogin()
{
//..
}
```

But, once it goes to login page, all the data from current page is lost. I want to somehow save the current info and as soon as the user is logged in I want to let him post.

Current scenario: Once the user is logged in, the whole page is refreshed and he has to again come down to the item he wanted to comment and proceed.

Comment: First show what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: My code:

private async void PostIfLoggedIn(bool activateAddComment)
{
 //..
//..        
}

Comment: You can update your answer, if you want to post something long.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Navigation Pushmodalasync and popmodalasync.  PushModalAsync accepts a Content Page, in which in  that content page when you are finished performing authentication you call popModalAsync and return back to your post.

Comment: Well I am using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Droid, Can I use them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVMCross need to make use of init() func in view models to pass parameters and navigate based on that.